# I am trying to make prims algorithm using c++ STL. After the iterator iterates 1st time it stops the code and gives wrong output

Tags: c++, stl, minimum-spanning-tree, prims-algorithm

First I have created an un-directed graph of vertices, edges and weights.

In `prims()` function:

- `vertex[]` array is initialized to `INT_MAX` for all indices `i < n` except `0` index. It will have smallest weights found till now.
- `bool isthere[]` array to check either a  vertex is visited or not.
- `list<int> s` at first will have `5 (0-4 indices)` values. After each for loop its value will pop.
- `vector<int> mset` will keep the vertex chosen according to their smallest weight.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void addEdge(vector<pair<int,int>>adj[],int u,int v,int wt){
    adj[u].push_back(make_pair(v,wt));
    adj[v].push_back(make_pair(u,wt));
}
void print(vector<pair<int,int>>adj[],int v){
    for(int i=0;i<v;++i){
        cout<<i<<"-->";
        vector<pair<int,int>>::iterator it;
        for(it=adj[i].begin();it!=adj[i].end();++it){
            cout<<it->first<<"-"<<it->second<<" ";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
}
void prims(vector<pair<int,int>>adj[],int v){
    int vertex[v];
    bool isthere[v];
    vertex[0]=0;
    isthere[0]=true;
    list<int>s;
    s.push_back(0);
    for(int i=1;i<v;++i){
        vertex[i]=INT_MAX;
        isthere[i]=false;
        s.push_back(i);
    }
    vector<int>mset;
    int i=0;
    while(!s.empty()){
    isthere[i]=true;
    mset.push_back(i);
    s.pop_back();
    cout<<"i="<<i<<" ";
    int lesser=INT_MAX;
    vector<pair<int,int>>::iterator it;
    for(it=adj[i].begin();it!=adj[i].end();++it){
            cout<<"it-"<<it->first<<" "<<it->second<<"\n";
        if(isthere[it->first]==false && vertex[it->first]>it->second){
          if(lesser>it->second){
                lesser=it->second;
                i=it->first;
                cout<<"i="<<i<<" ";
            }
          vertex[it->first]=it->second;

        }
    }
    }
}
int main(){
    int v=5;
    vector<pair<int,int>>adj[v];
    addEdge(adj,0,1,2);
    addEdge(adj,0,2,8);
    addEdge(adj,1,3,21);
    addEdge(adj,4,1,6);
    addEdge(adj,2,1,0);
    addEdge(adj,2,4,5);
    addEdge(adj,3,4,9);
    print(adj,v);
    prims(adj,v);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's my adjacency list. It is an array of vector of pairs denoting vertex, weight.

```
0-->1-2  2-8

1-->0-2  3-21  4-6  2-0

2-->0-8  1-0  4-5

3-->1-21  4-9

4-->1-6  2-5  3-9
```

Here's the debug output and the error I got in the `prims()` function.

```
i=0  it-1 2

i=1  it-2 8

it-0  0

it- -874898181 134251312

Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 0.835 s
Press any key to continue.
```

[image: Photo attached of output on console]

Comment: Use a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` for your adjacency list. declaring arrays using runtime integers is specific to gcc

Comment: What did you see when you debugged your code?

Comment: `int vertex[v];` -- This is not valid C++.  You are already using `std::vector`, so the question is -- do you know the purpose of `std::vector`?  It is to do what that non-C++ code you have now is supposed to do.  `std::vector<int> vertex(n);` is standard C++.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(it=adj[i].begin();it!=adj[i].end();++it){
  // ...
  i=it->first;
  // ...
}
```

This code exhibits undefined behavior, as it compares an iterator into one container with iterator into a different one. `it` is initialized with, say, `adj[0].begin()`, then `i` changes inside the loop, and on the next iteration the iterator is compared with, say, `adj[1].end()`